# sorting date field with datatype as varchar2 in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, date-arithmetic, date-conversion

I need to sort a varchar2 datatype column with date value in number format as `YYMM` to `MMYY`

The value ranges from

```
3
6
9
12
103
.
.
9909
9912
```

The value with 4 characters in length denotes the year between 1900 and 1999 
less than 4 characters denotes the year starts with 2000 and above.

I tried using LPAD(fieldname, 4,'0') which returns value as

```
0003 this is nothing but 2000/03
0006 ------------------- 2000/06
0009
0012
0103 ------------------- 2001/03
.
.
9912 ------------------- 1999/12
```

how can i order the column based on the year value starting from 1900 in ascending order .
Can anyone please provide me the solution....

Comment: One of the option is to turn it into a date using appropriate format mask: `order by to_date(lpad(col, 4, '0'), 'RRMM')` [Here is the SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/89663/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepend a century marker based on the length of the value:

```
select value,
  case when length(value) = 4 then '19' else '20' end || lpad(value, 4, '0') as dt
from t
order by case when length(value) = 4 then '19' else '20' end || lpad(value, 4, '0');

     VALUE DT   
---------- ------
      9909 199909 
      9912 199912 
         6 200006 
         9 200009 
        12 200012 
       103 200103
```

Or use the same thing and convert to a date, which defaults to the first day of each month:

```
select value, to_date(case when length(value) = 4 then '19' else '20' end
    || lpad(value, 4, '0'), 'YYYYMM') as dt
from t
order by to_date(case when length(value) = 4 then '19' else '20' end
    || lpad(value, 4, '0'), 'YYYYMM');

     VALUE DT       
---------- ----------
      9909 1999-09-01 
      9912 1999-12-01 
         6 2000-06-01 
         9 2000-09-01 
        12 2000-12-01 
       103 2001-03-01
```

If you're only looking at dates within the Y2K-safe range of 1950-2049, you could skip the century part and use an RR date model instead, though since this will potentially cause you problems later there isn't really any advantage over using the length to prepend the century:

```
select value, to_date(lpad(value, 4, '0'), 'RRMM') as dt
from t
order by to_date(lpad(value, 4, '0'), 'RRMM');

     VALUE DT       
---------- ----------
      9909 1999-09-01 
      9912 1999-12-01 
         6 2000-06-01 
         9 2000-09-01 
        12 2000-12-01 
       103 2001-03-01
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/300f6/2).

Comment: @user1719115 - what happens when you have a value representing a date after 2009; if you had 1001 for example, would you want that to be 1910 or 2010? If the latter, that may make the RR approach more practical, though if you want a different [cutoff than 1950](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#i116004). Which would need a more complicated case statement, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish the existing four digit values first, so you know they're 20th century dates before you pad out the rest.

Then convert it to a date and fiddle with the format to get the sort order you require :

```
 select to_char( expanded_dt, 'MMYYYY') as switched_dt
 from (
     select to_date(
                  case when length(dt) = 4 then '19'||dt
                  else '20'||lpad(dt,4,'0') end 
             , 'YYYYMM' )
                 as expanded_dt
      from your_table
     )
order by 1 asc
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is a bad design to store **DATE** values as **VARCHAR2** and using only **partial elements**. In the long run, you should first fix your design.

As a workaround, if the year values are in the range `1950-2049` you could use **`RR`** format for the **two digit years**.

```
TO_DATE(LPAD(date_column, 4,'0'), 'RRMM')
```

**`LPAD`** will add the required leading zeros.

For example,

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='MM/DD/YYYY';

Session altered.

SQL> WITH dates AS(
  2  SELECT '3' dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT '6' dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT '9' dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT '12' dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT '103' dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT '9909' dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  8  SELECT '9912' dt FROM dual
  9  )
 10  SELECT dt,
 11         TO_DATE(LPAD(dt, 4,'0'), 'RRMM') date_val
 12  FROM dates
 13  ORDER BY date_val;

DT   DATE_VAL
---- ----------
9909 09/01/1999
9912 12/01/1999
3    03/01/2000
6    06/01/2000
9    09/01/2000
12   12/01/2000
103  03/01/2001

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So, the above query gives you the desired output, the date values are now sorted in ascending order.